# Dynamic Query is not working with cursor in SqlServer 2008 Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am building a stored procedure in Sql Server 2008. Stored Procedure has two arguments which are the column names of a table. In stored procedure I used dynamic query for fetching data of these two columns with the help of Cursor.

Code:

```
    Create PROCEDURE TestSP
(
@firstAttribute nvarchar(max),
@secondAttribute nvarchar(max)
)
AS 
DECLARE @x FLOAT
DECLARE @y INT
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @cursor_query nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @result_Cursor as cursor

BEGIN
SET @query = 'Select '+ @firstAttribute+','+@secondAttribute+' from TBL_TEST_DATA_NEW'
SET @cursor_query =' set @cursor = cursor for ' + @query +' open @cursor;'

PRINT 'CURSOR_QUERY'+@cursor_query

exec sys.sp_executesql
    @cursor_query
    ,N'@cursor cursor output'
    ,@result_Cursor output

FETCH NEXT FROM result_Cursor INTO @x, @y
```

But when I am executing this SP it is giving me following error

```
Msg 16916, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TestSP, Line 33
A cursor with the name 'result_Cursor' does not exist.
```

Execute Command :

```
Exec TestSP "Column_1","Column_2"
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error

Please Help..

Thanks

Comment: Add **@** to your parameter **result_Cursor**  and retry:
`FETCH NEXT FROM @result_Cursor INTO @x, @y`

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that Cursor does not exist. You can't start with "set cursor". Also cursor name is without @.

So try using

```
declare cursorNameHere cursor for SELECT ...
open cursorNameHere
```

Answer (score 1):

`@result_Cursor` is a variable, just change your last line to

```
FETCH NEXT FROM @result_Cursor INTO @x, @y
```

see example on **<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6bbc/1)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

change

```
PRINT 'CURSOR_QUERY'+@cursor_query
```

to

```
PRINT 'CURSOR_QUERY '+@cursor_query
```